# What type of fastener / rivet is this please?

Tags: bearings, fasteners, bolting, rivets, hinge

I think I may have worked this out but I would love it if a real engineer could confirm it please?  Is the fixing shown in the photos a shoulder rivet?  Semi tubular?  For the record the pictures show a collapsible music stand, the metal legs shown are both about 5mm thick and the fastener / rivet's diameter is approx 10mm on both visible ends.  The two metal leg parts both freely pivot on this fastener so it’s essentially a hinge (bearing?) allowing the stand to fold up, but are also securely fixed together by it so there is no wiggle and it’s really sturdy, so it’s the perfect tightness.

I’m trying to prototype a similar part by hand so might struggle with a heavy duty machine rivet if that’s what it is, is there a locking / screwing equivalent I could try?  Any other advice on securely fixing two movable flat leg parts is most appreciated.

Thanks!
[image: Side 1]
[image: Side 2]

Comment: I haven't used these myself for any work, but looks like a *hollow rivet* or *tubular rivet*, perhaps with a shoulder to maintain clearance so the joint can rotate, but that may not be necessary if it isn't hollow the whole way through

Comment: Note that the clinching of the rivet should have a hard stop or pressure stop so that you don't bite so hard that the hinge is locked.

Comment: Re: prototyping - besides a *binding post* or similar hardware per Phil Sweet's answer, you could use a *shoulder screw* + washer & nut & loctite. Some shops more likely to have these on hand. If necessary with additional washers under the head to tweak the clearance.

Answer (score 1):

Generically called barrel bolts or structural panel fasteners.

[image]

https://www.grainger.com/product/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Architectural-Bolt-20X885

Comment: This isn't the same thing, although it does answer the last part of the question, about an easier to prototype with alternative

Comment: Fantastic, thanks all for your help!